# Create intervals from integers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for efficient ways for creating the `Interval`,

```
Interval - (startIndex [inclusive], endIndex [exclusive])
```

from the `unsorted integer array`.

For example,

```
Array A - [3, 1, 8, 5, 11, 10, 2]
```

should result in `ordered list` of `Interval`

```
ordered-List - [(1, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9), (10, 12)]
```

My initial thought is to **sort** this and scan from left to right creating the intervals understanding where the next element is not continuous.

Can we do this in linear time using modified `Interval Tree` concept, or is there any better way to do this?

PS: I'm OK with `O(N)` space.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: Since my range lies in [0:1000], and number of elements at a time should be no more than 1000, I went through sorted way, however I still see the opportunity of improving this. My code:

```
private class Interval {
    private final int startIndex; // inclusive
    private final int endIndex; // exclusive

    private Interval(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        Validate.isTrue(startIndex >= 0, "start-index (0-based): " + startIndex + ",  is lesser than 0.");
        Validate.isTrue(startIndex < endIndex, "start index " + startIndex + ", is out of bound with respect to end index " + endIndex + ".");
        Validate.isTrue(endIndex <= numberOfSlides(), "end index " + endIndex + ", points to slide that doesn't exist.");

        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    private int getRange() {
        return this.endIndex - this.startIndex;
    }

    private int startIndex() {
        return this.startIndex;
    }
}

private List<Interval> createIntervals(int[] slideIndexes) {
    Validate.notNull(slideIndexes, "The array of slide indexes is null!");
    Validate.isTrue(slideIndexes.length != 0, "The array of slide indexes is empty!");
    final List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(slideIndexes);        
    int curStart = slideIndexes[0], lastLink = curStart + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < slideIndexes.length; i++) {
        if (slideIndexes[i] == lastLink - 1) { // handles duplicates!
            continue;
        } else if (slideIndexes[i] != lastLink) {
            intervals.add(new Interval(curStart, lastLink));
            curStart = slideIndexes[i];
        }
        lastLink = slideIndexes[i] + 1;
    }
    intervals.add(new Interval(curStart, lastLink));

    return intervals;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried your idea? Also, if you use Guava, you can use `Range`.

Comment: If you have to _sort_ first, your algorithm must be at least O(n log n).

Comment: Well I can implement the sort way but that is O(NlgN), I was looking for some thing linear (or may be less, but seems not possible). I don't use Guava but I should take a look upon the Range implementation. I use apache  common library, if there is any equivalent in apache?

Comment: Ok with `O(n)`? I think this is the minimum what can be accomplished since you'll definitely need to scan the array. Have you tried scanning for the gaps? Maybe you should post an attempt as well.

Comment: yep O(n) time, and space, this is what I was looking upon.

Comment: What is the range of element in this array?

Comment: @PhamTrung, The elements could be in range of 50 to 1000.

Comment: By range if you mean number of elements in array - 50 to 1000. But if by range you mean the lower number possible, or larger number possible, then its 0 - 1000. The array should contain non-negative integers.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be duplicates in the array?

Comment: @Sildoreth Oh I haven't thought about that. Ideally there should not be any duplicates but if they occur I might need to remove those, or not to process them.

Comment: Think. The problem is easy given sorted input, so sort first. The problem can't be solved any faster, because it asks for sorted output (in the case the numbers are sparse, the problem is exactly sorting).

Answer (score 2):

If the value of each element in array A is small, we can use a frequency table `fre` to mark the occurrence of each element in A.

```
int[]fre = //
for(int i : A)
   fre[i]++;
```

After this, you can apply your old algorithm on array `fre` to create those intervals.

```
for(int i = 50; i <= 1000; i++){
    if(fre[i] == 0){
       //Do something
    }else{
       //Do other thing
    }
}
```

Time complexity of this Algorithm is **O(max(n,1000))**, with n is the number of element in `A`.

Comment: If array is [3, 1, 8, 5, 11, 10, 2, 1000], then I need to create the extra hash array of [1-1000], where most of the values will be sparse. Not bad but the space is not O(N) but depends on max/min in array, where finding min and max again is a traversal. May be I'm thinking two much since problem is not big in terms of elements.

Comment: @Prakhar you can use this algo if n log n > 1000, and use your old algo for case n is small. I don't think with n < 1000, O(n) or O(n log n) solution have hug difference

Comment: This is what I was thinking, may be I'm thinking too much for this problem. Anyways thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do better than O(n log n) in the general case unless you use extra space proportional to the highest value item, as shown in Pham Trung's algorithm, which is basically a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Creating a set of contiguous intervals for an unsorted list of items is at its heart a sorting algorithm. For example, imagine that your list of items is [7,0,3,9,8,4,5,2,1,6]. That is the single closed interval (0,10). If you could compute that in less than O(n log n) time without using extra memory, then you could sort an arbitrary array in less than O(n log n) time. But we already know that [comparison sorting has a lower bound of O(n log n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list).

Granted, if you know that your array contains a single closed interval, then if you know the min and max, you can sort it in linear time. But if you don't know how many intervals the items in the array represent, then you either end up using a non-comparison sort (counting sort, radix sort, etc.) with additional space at least proportional to N, or you do a comparison sort.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is:

1. Use a fast sorting algorithm to sort the list first

   - I recommend either [MergeSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), [HeapSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), or [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
2. Loop through the sorted list – as you said – and account for the non-contiguous cases

Yes, this will give you a runtime of O(n log n).  But unless you're expecting the array to be super-huge – like 1 million elements or more – this should not be a problem.  Ultimately, this approach should be adequately fast.

For what it's worth, there aren't even 1 million seconds in a day: `(24 hours) * (60 mins/hour) * (60 secs/min) = 86400 seconds`.  I don't know if that's applicable, but you *are* using a class named "Interval", which tends to hint at "time".

Comment: Your sort-then-group approach is going to be the only reasonable way to do it if the list is large, because any other solution will require the use of at least O(N) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm fine with O(N) space.